# Authorization in .NET core 3.1 and WPF

Tags: wpf, authorization, .net-core-3.1

I’m developing a WPF desktop application based on .NET Core 3.1. I need to implement some sort of authorization as users need access to different parts of the application.

I need something that works in a similar way to Code Access Security (in .Net Framework) or the Authorize Attribute (in ASP.NET), but I’m unable to figure out what technology to use / how to do it.

I therefor turn to the bright minds that rome this site for help – How can I get a CAS like functionality on .NET Core 3.1 in a WPF application?

Comment: Is this an internal app. Active directory and groups would be your simplest route.

Answer (score 1):

Declarative security actions using the [PrincipalPermission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.permissions.principalpermissionattribute?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) and the approach suggested [here](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/03/24/custom-authorization-in-wpf/) is not supported in .NET Core.

You should be able to do imperative checks against the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` property and explicitly throw `UnauthorizedAccessExceptions` in your code though.

Note that there was a [bug fix](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31717) on setting the PrincipalPolicy backported to .NET Core 3.1.

Comment: Is there a way to throw the Authorize attribute on methods or is it required to explicitly check roles against the Thread.CurrentPrincipal?